# Did Ravana know Rama more powerful than 1000s of Vishnus, Brahmas and Rudras/Shankaras?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, ramayana, rama, brahma

Hanumanji said:

> संकर सहस बिष्नु अज तोही। सकहिं न राखि राम कर द्रोही॥ (4)
>
> Listen, O ten-headed Ravana, I tell you on oath: there is none to save him who is opposed to Sri Rama. **Shankara, Vishnu and Brahma in their thousands are unable to protect you**, an enemy of Sri Rama. ([Sundarkand](https://www.bhaktiyogdarshan.com/ramayan/sunderkand-meaning-02.html))

Some say Ravana already knew this. Is it true? Maybe it is given in some Purana

Comment: you mean this https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?tid=3&tid_1=11&tid_2=8 ?

Comment: Even if Ravan knew, he always thought SrīRàm to be a normal human being. He never considered him as divine. For example, in Sunderkand, when the 2 dutas return after spying SrīRàm's Army. Ravan starts laughing and say, SrīRàm just like humans fellow is meditating for the sea to give him a way to Lanka . And there are many such incidents where Ravana, calls SrīRàm as  mere human, this was because of his ignorance that even after hearing the Kirti of SrīRàm from vibhishana, ŚrīHanuman, Mandodari, Mata  Sita, Rishi pulastya, Kumbhkaran and  2 of his dootas, he still turns the ear deaf to them.

Comment: @Chamundadas Please give sources and answer if you can!

Comment: @YDS I don't know?

Comment: @R.Kaushik sure!